# Como criar uma requisição via GET

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, pdo

Esse atributo abaixo está funcionando com **href**, e me direcionando para a página desejada.

```
<a href="prod_detalhe_5.php?codigo=<?php echo $res['codigo']; ?>">
    <img src="img_produtos/<?php echo $res['img01']; ?>" />
</a>
```

Gostaria de usar uma **REQUISIÇÃO** para abrir o item selecionado em uma **DIV** com a **Class** de nome **visual** para que não haja refresh na página.

Tentei criar o atributo com o script abaixo mas sem sucesso, pois quando clico no link não acontece nada, ele não me direciona para a página **prod_detalhe_5.php** com os dados do produto e não me informa nenhum tipo de erro, fica totalmente estático.

```
<a class="detalhe" style="cursor:pointer;" id="<?php echo $res['codigo']; ?>">
    <img style="width:100%; max-width:100px;" src="img_produtos/<?php echo $res['img01']; ?>" />
</a>

<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.detalhe').click(function(){
        var cod = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            url:'prod_detalhe_5.php?codigo='+cod,success:function(data){
            $('#visual').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Com os dados do atributo funcionando com o **href**, os amigos podem me mostrar onde estou errando no script, ou mesmo me dar uma dica de como devo proceder para fazer com que eu consiga abrir a **prod_detalhe_5.php** com os dados dos produtos usando uma **REQUISIÇÃO AJAX** para evitar o refresh da página.

Agradeço desde já a atenção de todos ao meu problema.

Comment: Para deixar sua pergunta mais completa, informe se retorna algo, algum erro.

Comment: Olá Mauro Alexandre, editei a pegunta com o que está acontecendo com mais detalhes, OK?

Comment: Chegou a olhar o console (F12) se aparece algum erro?

Comment: Está apresentando esse erro da imagem no Console, ai ferrou pois não tenho ideia do que seja ou como resolver... Ajuda amigos...Rsrsrsrssr...





  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0Boj.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Se for somente um link você pode usar um id ao invés de uma classe, e também pode usar o atributo data, veja um exemplo.

```
 <a id="detalhes" style="cursor:pointer;" data-id="<?php echo $res['codigo']; ?>">
    <img style="width:100%; max-width:100px;" src="img_produtos/<?php echo $res['img01']; ?>" />
</a>

<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#detalhes').click(function(){
        var cod = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $.ajax({
            url:'prod_detalhe_5.php?codigo='+cod,success:function(data){
            $('#visual').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Espero que te ajude.

Comment: Usou um querySelector para usar o jQuery depois? Não seria melhor fazer direto no jQuery mesmo? Assim `$('#detalhes').click(function(){`

Comment: Pode ser Guilherme, só criei uma variável por costume mesmo.